# .Net Core 5 ViewComponent Model on cshtml is always null

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm working on some ViewComponent but when I try to Access the Model in the cshtml file it's always null.

Here is a very simple example that has this problem
This is the .cs code

```cs
[ViewComponent(Name = "CssHelper")]
public class CssHelperViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public CssHelperViewComponent()
    {
    }

    private bool IsDarkMode;

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
            IsDarkMode = false;
        if (HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("darkmode", out var darkmode))
            IsDarkMode = true;
        return View(IsDarkMode);
    }
}
```

and this is the cshtml

```html
@page
@model bool
@if (Model)
{
    <link href="assets/css/style.dark.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/global/plugins.dark.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
@if (!Model)
{
    <link href="assets/css/style.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
```

I receive a

**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Root_Namespace.Pages.Components.CssHelper.Pages_Components_CssHelper_Default.get_Model()**

on @if (Model.Value)

What I'm doing wrong?
I have this problem on several ViewComponent so maybe I'm repeating the same error on all items.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your model "ExtBool"?

Comment: I've simplified code without use my custom type. The result is the same using bool as return type

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the directive

```
@page
```

in the cshtml file. Removing that, the model is binded correctly.